# Add a car to a map based on its model

Tags: java, collections, stream

I have a map of cars `Map<String, Set<Car>>` which can be returned by `getCarsMap()` method where key is model of car , and value is list of cars of same model.

I would like to improve Car `addCar(Car car)` function. For now I wrote this a bit ugly piece of code.

```
public Car addCar(Car car) {
if(getCarsMap().entrySet().stream().anyMatch(es -> es.getKey().equals(car.getModel()))){
    if(!getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).contains(car)){
        getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).add(car);
    }
}else{
    Set<Car> tmpSet = new HashSet<Car>();
    tmpList.add(car);
    getCarsMap().put(car.getModel(), tmpSet) ;
}
return car;}
```

Since purpose is to learn streams, lambdas etc. (java8) I would love to use as these things as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

There is not need to go to streams at all for a piece of functionality already implemented in the `containsKey` member function of `Map`.

```
if(getCarsMap().containsKey(car.getModel())){
    if(!getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).contains(car)){
        getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).add(car);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's [`Map.computeIfAbsent(K, Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) for this:

```
getCarsMap().computeIfAbsent(car.getModel(), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(car);
```

The `Set.contains()` check before calling the `add(T)` method is redundant, as a `Set` will contain unique elements.

Also, since Java 7, you can rely on [generic type inference for object creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), i.e. a `new HashSet<>()` instead of a `new HashSet<Car>()`.